# Составление системы уравнения

Tags: c++

Всем привет. Возникла проблема при составлении системы уравнения. В двумерный массив добавляю уравнения(они не даны сразу, я их добавляю и мне надо проверить подойдет ли это уравнение):

```
1011
1207
0308
```

Где первые 3 значения коэффиценты, а 4 число ответ. Чтобы мне решить эту систему Гауссом, уравнения должны быть линейно независимые и не должно быть столбца из одних 0. При добавлении я проверяю строку на линейно независимую с предыдущей таким образом:

```
void algorithm(int a,int b,int p)
{
    vector<int> vector1(3);
    vector<int> vector2(3);
    vector1[0] = 5;
    vector1[1] = 3;
    vector1[2] = 2;
    int mas[3][4];
    int r = 0;
    int e = 0;
    int s = 1;
    int c = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            mas[i][j] = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < vector1.size(); i++)
    {
        r = powmod(a,s,p);
        mas[i][3] = s+p-1;//тут заносим ответ системы
        while (e!=vector1.size()) // тут мы считаем коэффиценты у уравнения
        {
            if (r%vector1[e] == 0)
            {
                r /= vector1[e];
                mas[i][e]++;
            }
            else
                e++;
        }

         if(i != 0)//тут проверяем на нелинейность
        {
             for (int j = 0; j < vector1.size(); j++)
             {
                 c = mas[i][j] * mas[i - 1][j];
             }
        }
         if ((r != 1) || (c != 0))//тут мы удаляем уравнения если оно получилось линейнозависимое, или наше число нельзя польностью разложить
         {
             for (int j = 0; j < vector1.size(); j++)
                 mas[i][j]=0;
             i--;
         }

        e = 0;
        s++;
    }
}
```

Если получилось линейно зависимое то я удаляю заполненную строку и добавляю другое равнение. Правильно ли я делаю? Как еще параллельно сделать проверку, чтобы не было столбца из одних 0?
[image: Примерно так должно быть]

Comment: *При добавлении я проверяю строку на линейно независимую с предыдущей* А не проще тупо проверить, что главный определитель ненулевой? *Если получилось линейно зависимое то я удаляю заполненную строку и добавляю другое* А не проще изменить (скажем, плюс один) один из коэффициентов? для устойчивости - имеющий минимальное по абсу значение...

Comment: Просто решайте Гауссом (лучше с выбором главного элемента). Если получите в какой-то момент всю строку нулевую - значит, имеется линейная зависимость. А заранее проверять - какой смысл? Или у вас задача - составить систему уравнений? Ваш метод в любом случае плох, так как не отслеживает линейную зависимость с несколькими (не с одним) уравнениями.

Comment: Моя задача составить систему уравнения.То еть, где я написал матрицу, мне ее и надо правильно составить

Comment: @Александр Можете добавить весь код? Мне кажется у Вас скобок не хватает, потому что Вы в цикле постоянно меняете значение переменной c, а проверяете её значение лишь после выхода из цикла.

Comment: так и надо. Линейно независимое уравнение, если все коэффиценты попарно перемножить и сумма будет равно 0.

Comment: @Александр Вы пишете, что именно сумма должна быть равна нулю, но у Вас переменная c вообще ни с чем не складывается, в неё лишь на каждой итерации цикла вносится произведение элементов матрицы. Если Вы считаете, что это правильно, то я в свою очередь вижу здесь явное нерациональное использование переменной c. Или там всё же должно быть c += mas[i][j] * mas[i - 1][j]; ?

Comment: складывать надо)

Comment: @Александр Ну так складывайте. Внимательно проверьте код, у вас там шатких мест много. И не забудьте потом обновить вопрос с учётом найденных Вами ошибок.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71222/discussion-between-roman-podymov-and-).

Comment: Я думаю, просто не правильно пытаюсь реализовать эту систему уравнения. Как ее правильно составить? Получил я одно уравнение добавил в массив, затем проверил с предыдущим на нелинейность и так далее пока не будет квадратная матрица? Или надо сначала добавлять уравнения до квадратной матрицы, а затем ее всю проверить на нелинейность и все ли используются коэффиценты. Как правильно, надо сделать вопрос

Comment: @Александр Я Вам в чате ответил, проверьте пожалуйста.